# Number of children

Tags: mathematics

Here comes an easy one:

> A Family has several children.
> Each brother has the same numbers of brothers and sisters, but each sister has twice as many brothers as sisters

How many sisters and brothers does this family have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are

> $4$ brothers and $3$ sisters

because we can solve the equation

> $b - 1 = s$, $2(s - 1) = b$.